# how to define piecewise function from naturals to naturals in coq

Tags: coq

How can I define a function like f(x)=0 if x<5 otherwise f(x)=1 in Coq?

If I do something like in OСaml,

```
Definition test (i:nat):nat :=
  if i < 5 then 0 else 1.
```

It complains that

> Error: The term `i < 5` has type `Prop` which is not a (co-)inductive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a *decidable* version of the comparison (`i < 5` is a logical or propositional version, which you can't compute with). This is in the standard library:

```
Require Import Arith.
Check lt_dec.

Definition test (i:nat) : nat := if lt_dec i 5 then 0 else 1.
```

The standard library's test for less than returns not a boolean but actually a sumbool, which includes proofs in both cases to tell you what the function does (these proofs go unused in your example, but would be handy if you wanted to prove something about `test`). The `{n < m} + {~n < m}` type you see in `lt_dec`'s type is notation for `sumbool (n < m) (~n < m)`.

If you didn't care about proofs, then you can use a different function, `Nat.ltb`, that returns a boolean. The standard library includes convenient notation for this function as well:

```
Require Import Arith.

Definition test (i:nat) : nat := if i <? 5 then 0 else 1.
```

When you work with this in proofs, you'll need to apply a theorem like `Nat.ltb_lt` to reason about what `i <? 5` returns.

Note that the `if b then .. else ...` in Coq supports `b` being either a bool or a sumbool. In fact, it supports *any* inductive type with two constructors and uses the `then` branch for the first constructor and the `else` branch for the second; the definitions for `bool` and `sumbool` are careful to order their constructors to make `if` statements behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. However, what I actually want is something like Definition word(i:nat)(j:nat)(n:nat):nat =
  if le_dec j i then i+1-j
    else if lt_dec j i+n-1 then
      j-i+1
      else if j=i+n-1 then
        0
        else 2*n+i-j. Why does coq complain that "The term "i + 1 - j" has type "nat"
while it is expected to have type "Set"." ?

Comment: You are likely using the wrong equality, try with `=?`.